# Website not working in Firefox/Chrome, but does in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

There is a website that I must use at work quite a bit and the only browser it works on is Internet Explorer.

I'm presuming this is because the code is outdated/incorrect and includes javascript that only IE is able to read.

This is a problem, because I want to use Firefox or Chrome, they are much better browsers.

I believe the issue is Firefox/Chrome (hereinafter referred to as foam) not being able to recognize the following "onclick" command lines. When I press these buttons, the web page does not change as it should.

```
<button class="MenuButton" title="Create ICL" value="ADDICL" onclick="PageJump('ICLMain.asp?From=ICLHome')">Create ICL
```

So.... since this is not my website, I cannot re-write all of this code to fix it. It is a corporate owned underwriter website for creating a certain document.

There must be some sort of extension that enables Firefox/Chrome to read Javascript codes like Internet Explorer so that I can use Firefox/Chrome and still use this website.

Comment: Usually, it's the opposite :D

Comment: `onclick` works in all browsers, both old and modern.

Comment: Since I see that it is a classic ASP app, there are some javascript function that only works for IE. I would recommend checking what the PageJump function does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use chrome extension ie tab,  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=es. This extension emulate The ie Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same problem(Javascript broke). The solution I found is to just add https:// before the link and reload the page and everything will work fine again.